# Analytic functions in the unit disk with radial limit zero.

Tags: complex-analysis

In the following paper:

### http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1955-006-01/S0002-9939-1955-0068625-6/S0002-9939-1955-0068625-6.pdf

there is the following claim.

> Examples have been given [5, p. 185] of functions $f(z)$, analytic in the
>   unit-circle $K$: $|z| <1$, and not identically constant, for which the
>   radial $\text{limit} f(e^{i\theta}) =\lim_{r\to 1}f(re^{i\theta})$ is zero for all $e^{i\theta}$  on $|z| =1$ except
>   for a set of linear measure zero. In view of the Riesz-Nevanlinna
>   theorem [6, p. 197], such functions cannot be bounded, or even of
>   bounded characteristic, in $|z| < 1$.

This is not very intuitive as it seems at first contradictory to the maximum modulus principle applied in $\mathbb{D}$. Can someone explain what is actually happening here?

Answer (score 1):

When you say

> This is not very intuitive as it seems at first contradictory to the maximum modulus principle applied in $\mathbb{D}$

I think you are probably trying to interchange the two limits $r\uparrow 1$ and $\sup_\theta$, which is a big no-no.  Indeed, the $f$ in this example has
$$
\sup_\theta \lvert f(re^{i\theta})\rvert\to\infty\text{ as }r\uparrow 1.
$$
i.e., $f\notin H^\infty$.  In fact, it isn't in any $H^p$.

A toy example, to get a feeling of what could be happening, is to work with harmonic functions.  The Poisson kernel
$$
P_r(\theta)=\operatorname{Re}\frac{1+re^{i\theta}}{1-re^{i\theta}}=\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2}
$$
is harmonic on $\mathbb{D}$ and satisfies $\lim_{r\uparrow 1}P_r(\theta)\to 0$ for almost all $\theta$ (indeed, as long as $\cos\theta\neq 1$).  However, this isn't the full counterexample because the conjugate Poisson kernel
$$
Q_r(\theta)=\operatorname{Im}\frac{1+re^{i\theta}}{1-re^{i\theta}}=\frac{2r\sin\theta}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2}
$$
does not have (almost everywhere) constant radial limit.

You can read Lusin's original paper [here](http://archive.numdam.org/item/ASENS_1925_3_42__143_0/), although according to David Hansen's answer in [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/a/52357) Hardy and Ramanujan might have a claim to be the first to construct such example.